# GKE Autopilote EgressNATPolicy with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gke-networking, autopilot

I'm creating a module for GKE autopilote using Terraform, currently my configuration is:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke-autopilote" {
  name    = var.name
  project = var.project_id

  location            = local.region
  enable_autopilot    = true
  deletion_protection = false
  network             = data.google_compute_network.gke_network.self_link
  subnetwork          = data.google_compute_subnetwork.gke_subnetwork.self_link
  networking_mode     = "VPC_NATIVE"

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name = local.ip_range_pods_name // 100.64.0.0/21
  }


  dynamic "private_cluster_config" {
    for_each = local.enable_private_endpoint ? [{
      enable_private_nodes    = local.enable_private_nodes,
      enable_private_endpoint = local.enable_private_endpoint
    }] : []
    content {
      enable_private_endpoint = private_cluster_config.value.enable_private_endpoint // false
      enable_private_nodes    = private_cluster_config.value.enable_private_nodes  // true
      dynamic "master_global_access_config" {
        for_each = local.master_global_access_enabled ? [local.master_global_access_enabled] : []
        content {
          enabled = master_global_access_config.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As mentionned in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot), GKE autopilote is created with ip-masquerading by default, and the configuration is stored in configmap called ip-masq-agent in kube-system namespace, but since it autopilote and we don't have acces to modify the configmap directly, Google  propose to do it with a CDR called egressnatpolicies : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot#edit-default-egress-nat-policy

My issue is when I create the cluster with the console able able to find the objec 'egressnatpolicies' but when I create the cluster with my module I cannot find it :

`error: the server doesn't have a resource type "egressnatpolicies"`

Note: in both cases, I'm able to find the daemonSet for ip-masq-agent